# Make first letter capital

Tags: php, regex

I have this code snippet, where I want to change the first letter to capital. But I couldn't manage make it working.

`preg_replace('/(<h3[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/h3>)/i', '$1'.ucfirst('$2').'$3', $bsp)`

Comment: show the world and what you want to replace in simple wording

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning:** HTML is not a regular language and cannot be properly parsed using a regular expression. Use a [DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/1438393) instead.

```
$bsp = '<h3>hello</h3>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($bsp);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3') as $h3) {
    $h3->nodeValue = ucfirst($h3->nodeValue);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/143107)

---

But if you're absolutely sure that the markup format is *always* the same, you *can* use a regex. However, instead of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace), use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
$bsp = '<h3>hello</h3>';

echo preg_replace_callback('/(<h3[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/h3>)/i', function ($m) {
    return $m[1].ucfirst($m[2]).$m[3];
}, $bsp);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/143108)

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Yeah, I added a warning at the beginning. Also added an example with DOMDocument.

Comment: Thank you, this was excelent :)

Comment: @user3050047: Glad to have helped! :)

Comment: @user3050047 Have you looked at other answers? Regex is not the optimal solution here. Don't blindly use it.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: There's a DOM parser solution at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Be sure he did not use it. PHP room?

Comment: And what is the run-time cost of using DOM parser?

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Definitely larger than a regex. But in the long run, if you don't want broken code and weird markup, a DOM parser is always the optimal solution. It's guaranteed to work *always*, even with weird markups like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/702222/1438393).

Answer (score 5):

Using regex to parse HTML is always difficult. To avoid PHP and regex, I suggest using CSS and  the [text-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) property.

```
h3 { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution. Good thinking.

Comment: Yep, best solution if using CSS is an option. Hadn't thought of that. +1

Answer (score 0):

using a dom parser like this may be :

```
<?php
$html='<h3>hello world</h3>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo ucfirst($dom->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

outputs :

```
Hello world
```

Comment: That only works on the first element. Basing on his initial question, it's safer to assume he wants it to work on all h3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DOMXPath`:

```
<?php

$html = 'HTML String <h3>whatever</h3>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); //Don't add a default doctype.
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//h3') as $h3) {
    $h3->nodeValue = ucfirst($h3->nodeValue);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Will catch all `h3`s even if they aren't formatted exactly as you expect.

Comment: You don't need `item->` there. `$h3->nodeValue = ucfirst($h3->nodeValue);` is enough.

Answer (score -4):

Does the first letter capital - `echo ucfirst($str)`

Makes the first letter of every word in a capital - `echo ucwords($str)`